# Plane Separation Axiom (PSA) and Taxicab Geometry

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

The PSA states that:
A line $l$ separates a plane into two separate disjoint regions such that:

*i)* If points $P$ and $Q$ are in the same region, then the segment $\overline{PQ}$ does is fully contained in this same region.

*ii)* If points $P$ and $Q$ are in different regions, then the segment $\overline{PQ}$ intersects $l$.

Now, in Taxicab Geometry, it is easy to see that $i)$ is not true since you can have a line $l$ and two points $P$, $Q$ on the same side of $l$ and draw another line that joins $P$ to $Q$ passing through a point $R$ in the other side of $l$ (a quick drawing is enough to see this). This, of course, is keeping in mind that in taxicab geometry a line is sort of like a staircase.

I'm interested in finding a way to prove that *ii)* is true all the time. This time I don't just want to do a drawing because that would be for just one case, whereas we want to prove it true for all cases.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your exact definition of a "line" in the taxicab metric. Specifically, what is the line going through the points $A$ and $B$? Or are there several?

Comment: (assuming ii) is rephrased "all segments $\bar{PQ}$ intersect $l$") : what about plunging your taxicab-plan into the euclidian plan: any segment $\bar{PQ}$ is now a continuous curve with extremities on different sides of $l$ ($l$ is not a "line" anymore but stilll shares the plan is two halves), so we may be able to conclude that $\bar{PQ}$ intersects $l$ ?

Comment: @Arthur There are several. I don't have a formal definition but the best I can describe them as are curves with right angles, such that at each corner the direction of the angle is alternated.

Comment: @Evargalo if I understand correctly, what you're suggesting is that any curve with extremities on opposite sides of $l$ intersects $l$ in euclidean geometry. And since my taxicab "lines" are basically curves in the euclidean plane then they must intersect $l$?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea. I'm not litterate enough in the Euclidean axiomatic to built a proper proof, but that's the intuition.

Comment: Then I'm interested to know what "different regions" means to you if it isn't _defined_ by "every segment $\overline{PQ}$ intersects $l$".

Answer (score 0):

The usual modern approach in geometry is to treat point and line as undefined terms and develop a geometry from axioms. From this point of view taxicab geometry has as one of its axioms that two points determine a unique line. The usual model for taxicab geometry is that one interprets points as ordered pairs of real numbers and lines as linear equations, so the points and lines in the taxicab plane and the euclidean plane are the same from this point of view. What differs is the way distance between points works, so in the taxicab plane the distance from (a,b) to (c,d) is given by |a-c| + |b-d|. Typically, unlike for the euclidean plane, there are many ways to get from (a,b) to (c,d) that have the same length - but there is only one line between the points. Note, however, what is true for the distance from (0,0) to (3,0), say. Only, the line determined by these points achieves the length 3, unlike what is true for (0,0) to (3,3), where many "routes" have length 6. The axiom that the two geometries differ in is the congruence axiom, which if taken to be SAS does not hold for the model described above. As a result many theorems in euclidean geometry are no longer theorems in texicab geometry.